# Spring Boot Jpa @JoinColumn don't work

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot

So, hello again my dear comrades. I have meet a problem with spring boot jpa.
I can't join column. I'm using JpaRepository.
So here the code:
application.properties:

```
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/project_db?user=root&password=root
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Roles:

```
public enum Roles implements Serializable {
ROLE_USER,
ROLE_ADMIN
}
```

Users:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long Id;
@Basic
@Column(name = "username")
private String username;
@Basic
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;
@Basic
@Column(name = "fullname")
private String fullName;
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Roles.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private Set<Roles> roles;
```

Here Hibernate trying to save entities:

```
Hibernate: insert into users (fullname, password, username) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into user_roles (user_id, roles) values (?, ?)
```

Exception track trace:

```
`javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statementce.PersistenceException:
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ConnectionImple.registerDatabase - ARJUNA017017: enlist of resource failed
com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXAException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
java.sql.SQLException: ConnectionImple.registerDatabase - ARJUNA017017: enlist of resource failed
```

I think reason in this:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXAException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say, that another project without SpringBoot on Tomcat work good.

Comment: Are you sure this is related to @JoinTable?

Comment: I'm sure, cause when I save Entity without  Set<Contacts> it's fork fine.

Comment: please post the whole stacktrace. There must be more information about the problem

Comment: I guess problem was in `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXAException: No operations allowed after connection closed.`

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: I guess so, 4 years are gone, maybe the problem was incorrect entity configuration or maybe I had broken mysql deployed